# How do I run a python script with selenium that runs in an existing window?

Tags: python, selenium

I have to run a script that automates browsing on a few different pages that require logins.  Normally, the usernames and passwords for these pages are stored in the browser, but when I run selenium, it opens a new instance of the browser and prompts me for login information.  Is there any way to run the script in an existing instance of a browser so that I don't have to store login information in code?

Comment: currently there is no way to hijack a currently opened window, you may want to do research on how to run webdriver with options for example with chrome you can do `chromeopts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` then `chromeopts.add_argument('some argument here')` then `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chromeopts )` list of arguments are here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Is there any way to do this in firefox without Chromium?

Comment: yea, you can do it with any browser that accepts flags, check the API for the firefox equivilant. I only use it on Chrome so I don't know the exact object

Comment: you could always prompt the user for a username and password on the command line as well.  When the script starts, ask for the username and password and no credentials need to be stored in the code itself.